# h2o monte carlo cross-validation

Tags: r, cross-validation, h2o

I have a rare event I'm trying to predict (less than .01%) and wanted to implement Monte Carlo cross-validation (LGOCV in the caret package). How would I go about doing this in H2O? If this isn't available, where is this on the H2O roadmap? Thank you!

Comment: It's not available in h2o, but you could just do multiple runs with custom train/test splits